# LabVIEW: how to display different Images from different sources to one Image indicator

Tags: image, labview

I am working on an application on LabVIEW where I need to display a live camera and start saving images, in the other hand I want to visualize images from the folder (by clicking on "select images") to start going through images, I want to display what the camera captures and then what is saved in the folder from the same image indicator. is it possible with two while loops?
here's the front Panel and Block diagram.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you using 2 event structures? The event structure should be inside the while loop, otherwise, it will run only once.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this using a single while loop with an Event structure to handle all the events.[image: Event loop structure]

Adding events to this main Event structure, including a Timeout event (don't forget to wire the Timeout terminal) would allow you to enable or disable the camera capture calls provided they return within a few 100 ms. If the capture takes longer you would want to run a seperate loop that you can could enable/disable, possibly using a message queue.

Please check out the NI documentation on [event structures](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/glang/event_structure.html) and [message handlers](https://www.ni.com/en-gb/support/documentation/supplemental/21/using-a-queued-message-handler-in-labview.html) if these are not familiar to you.